# prevent (?i) to change to ({1}i) in a query String of PreparedStatement using neo4j-jdbc-3.5.1driver

Tags: jdbc, neo4j, cypher

The following lines of code

```
String query ="MATCH (n) WHERE n.name =~ '(?i).*SUBSTRING.*' RETURN n";
final PreparedStatement  statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
```

will change the query String
`"MATCH (n) WHERE n.name =~ '(?i).*SUBSTRING.*' RETURN n"`

in the prepareStatement (by using replacePlaceholders method )

to `"MATCH (n) WHERE n.name =~ '({1}i).*SUBSTRING.*' RETURN n"`

means it replace ? by {1}

How to prevent the change of `(?i)` and to not become `({1}i)` when passed to prepareStatement() and have always `(?i)` even if we pass via replacePlaceholders regex?

Below I give more info of the problem:

The same task that would perform as LIKE clause in Cypher queries is made by the following construct:

```
MATCH (n) where n.Name =~ '.*SUBSTRING.*' return n.Name, n;
```

and to make it case insensitive:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.name =~ '(?i).*SUBSTRING.*' RETURN n;
```

And by using neo4j-jdbc-3.5.1.jar

The org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jPreparedStatement.java

```
/**
 * Default constructor with connection and statement.
 *
 * @param connection   The JDBC connection
 * @param rawStatement The prepared statement
 */
protected Neo4jPreparedStatement(Neo4jConnection connection, String rawStatement) {
    super(connection);
    this.statement = PreparedStatementBuilder.replacePlaceholders(rawStatement);//<----LINE X
    this.parametersNumber = PreparedStatementBuilder.namedParameterCount(statement);
    this.parameters = new HashMap<>(this.parametersNumber);
    this.batchParameters = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And in org.neo4j.jdbc.utils.PreparedStatementBuilder

```
/**
     * This method return a String that is the original raw string with all valid placeholders replaced with neo4j curly brackets notation for parameters.
     * <br>
     * i.e. MATCH n RETURN n WHERE n.name = ? is transformed in MATCH n RETURN n WHERE n.name = {1}
     *
     * @param raw The string to be translated.
     * @return The string with the placeholders replaced.
     */
    public static String replacePlaceholders(String raw) {
        int index = 1;
        String digested = raw;

        String regex = "\\?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*$)";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(digested);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            digested = digested.replaceFirst(regex, "{" + index + "}");
            index++;
        }

        return digested;
    }
```

In replacePlaceholders() the `?` is transformed to `{1}`.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, they seem to be unconditionally replacing (in this case inside a string literal), instead of only replacing where a parameter can occur. You should report this to Neo4J. The workaround would seem to be to use a parameter here, and set your regular expression as the value of that parameter.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel  Thank you for answer. It is effectively a bug. I made a workaroud like your advice in your comment and it works. Please could you write your comment as an answer so I could Accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug to me, the Neo4J drivers seems to unconditionally replace question marks with the Neo4J parameter placeholder (in this case inside a string literal), instead of only replacing where a parameter can occur syntactically. You should report this to Neo4J.

The workaround would seem to me to use a parameter here, and set your regular expression as the value of that parameter.

That is, use

```
"MATCH (n) WHERE n.name =~ ? RETURN n"
```

And use `stmt.setString(1, "(?i).*SUBSTRING.*")` to set the expression for that variable on the prepared statement.

Or as you suggested yourself in the comments, use:

```
"MATCH (n) WHERE lower('n.name') contains lower(SUBSTRING) RETURN n"
```

Comment: Please update your answer and add this other option : or MATCH (n) WHERE lower('n.name')  contains lower(SUBSTRING) RETURN n